# How to put labels on mtail metrics for prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, exporter

```
# linecounter.mtail
counter line_count
/$/ {
  line_count++
}
```

For the `linecounter.mtail` program, `Prometheus` scrape `line_count{prog="linecounter.mtail",instance="bd0a0d119df6"} 2`

How to put additional `labels` in the `metric`?

I couldn't find any description on that.

Comment: How did you set up Prometheus and what kind of label do you want to add?

Comment: @svenwltr, Any label I want to put and is it relative to `Prometheus` setting? what if I want `mtail` to respond `metrics` containing `user-define-lebels`  against `mtail-host-ip:port/metrics` HTTP request.

Comment: I am looking for the same. @SangminKim by any chance did you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

Labels are automatically created by mtail, based on the declared metric !

All the metric lay in the metric declaration, like:

```
counter my_http_requests_total by log_file, request_method
```

#### Exemple:

Let's imagine you have an HTTP server log file, with `GET` and `POST`:

```
192.168.0.1 GET /foo
192.168.0.2 GET /bar
192.168.0.1 POST /bar
```

With the following Mtail program:

```
counter my_http_requests_total by log_file, request_method

/^/ +
/(?P<hostname>[0-9A-Za-z\.:-]+) / +
/(?P<request_method>[A-Z]+) / +
/(?P<URI>\S+).*/ +
/$/ {
    my_http_requests_total[getfilename()][$request_method][]++
}
```

Prometheus generated metrics would be :

```
my_http_requests_total{log_file="test.log",request_method="GET",prog="test.mtail"} 4242
my_http_requests_total{log_file="test.log",request_method="POST",prog="test.mtail"} 42
```

--

There are two magic metrics here (that can be mangled using Prometheus relabel rules) :

- `prog` is the mtail program name (*script*)
- The mtail function [getfilename()](https://github.com/google/mtail/blob/master/docs/Language.md) return the log file name containing the log line.